# Seemingly random reboot during OS installation

Tags: hard-drive, boot, cpu, reboot

I recently changed my motherboard, and as usual in this case my OS wouldn't boot properly (I got past login, then, after few seconds, reboot). I proceeded to fail-safe mode, backed up my data and begun preparations for system installation of Windows 8.1 Pro. I created a USB installation stick and started the installation.

When it got to part when setup is expanding files("setup is getting files ready" or something) bam! Reboot. No BSOD no warning, nothing just reboot. I've tried with two different sticks, two different ISO's (from MSDN) and Windows 7 ISO. Exactly same situation. I've booted Ubuntu from live stick and after few minutes same situation. Reboot with no warning. During Ubuntu installation it stated that it has problems with HDD I/O and it couldn't continue.

I checked the memory with MemTest86+, did a full HDD surface scan (S.M.A.R.T. is "good") - no errors. I tried doing a virus scan with AVG rescue disk and it rebooted during first second of scan. CMOS reset - DONE, cable check - DONE. I have no further ideas on how to proceed.

Background on motherboard change:

The PC reboots randomly - my first thought - temps. During mobo cleaning it seems that I've bent a socket pin (it was missing actually) so it wouldn't boot. A motherboard change was in order.

Specs:

- mobo: ASRock Z68-GEN3-PRO
- CPU: Intel Core i5-2400
- RAM: Kingston HyperX 8GB
- PSU: Corsair HX650

Comment: You haven't 'zapped' the motherboard whilst performing the change over have you? I've seen a lot of odd behavior from machines that I can only assume have had electrostatic discharge damage whilst being handled.

Comment: This board shows (on web) as having a lot of problems. sooo there are some thing you could try. Low-clock the ram, and the cpu (as best as you can) , disable all the C-states. Check tempertures while posted into the bios , stay there for some time and see if it does it there.  If what your saying is, the last board did some of the same things, then it could be a PSU issue. It could be a problem with case connections, just leave the case wiring (speaker, power, reset) disconnected from the MB, to test.  Check that the Heat sinc has proper refreshed quality thermal goop, and is seating properly.

Comment: Temp's are OK, 33 deg all the time in BIOS, after reboot it stay's below 40 deg. Nothing like that happens whilst in BIOS. Last board did that of course, but sporadically, so my guess it was temps as fans where pretty cloged with cat hairs. It seems that it happens only when some heavy I/O operations on HDD happens but I dunno if that's the case(could be coincidence). I'm trying with lower clocks and C-States disabled now.

Comment: Her computer randomly restarted before you replaced the motherboard.  It still reboots with the new motherboard.  This indicates there is a problem with the system drive.  Just to get clarification, you bent pin on the old motherboard, correct?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, as Psycogeek syggested - disabling C-States helped! Great catch my friend! Now, as I understand that they a resposnsible for energy management. Can u explain further? Are they supposed to be enabled? I'll try updating bios. Thank you very much :)

Comment: C-states allow the hardware to enter various states of sleep , halting the cpu to save power, and low and lower states of idleness. Adjusting them sometimes helps overclocking stability, at the costs of power wasting.  No I cannot explain further, one user suggested it helped the problem you were having, with the specific board. It had some logic behind it.